# What are some impressive examples of functional code?

Tags: functional-programming

I'm getting a bit tired of having to code explicitly for multicore if I want more speed, particularly when I'm just writing a one-off script.  My dev box already has 8 cores and that number is going up a lot faster than the clock speed.  Functional languages seem to offer a potential escape hatch, but I haven't put in the effort to master one of them yet.

I'd love to see some sample chunks of real-world code that are much better and/or more parallelizable than non-functional alternatives.  I'm not picky about the language -- I'm more interested in the concepts.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you running as a dev box that has 8 cores?

Comment: Yes -- it is a dual quad core Dell server.

Comment: That's why I keep it in the basement, far away from me :)

Comment: off-topic perhaps but my dev machine is a dual quad core xeon and doesn't make any noise :p

Comment: Just 3 years later, and I'm reading this on my fun-and-browsing laptop that has 8 virtual processors across 4 physical cores, and it's darn near silent ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (long, but very good) video gives both an intro to [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default.aspx) and a compelling demo of how easy it is to parallelize code in the language:

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/

Answer (score 6):

How about [MapReduce](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html)? It's incredibly parallelizable and even though it's not implemented in functional languages as far as the paper goes, it's inspired by Lisp's `map` and `reduce`.

Comment: And Hadoop, MapReduce's open source alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is asking for material right at the state of the art.  I think your best introduction to this field, with examples, is the book [Implicit Parallel Programming in pH](http://tinyurl.com/aepumf) by Nikhil and Arvind.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extended example of a text indexer/searcher using mapreduce in Chapter 20 ("Programming Multi-core CPUs") of [Programming Erlang](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang/programming-erlang). I don't know how impressive that is, but it looks like code mortals can write.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is a nice example of functional programming in mainstream languages. Reified code and monads? In MY C#? :) Anyways, w.r.t. threading, there's mention of [Parallel LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx). By using immutability and higher order functions (and Expression, perhaps), libraries can parallelize things for us.

And another link to F# with [async workflows](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2007/10/11/introducing-f-asynchronous-workflows.aspx). What's impressive is the ability to take sync code, and with a few small annotations turn it into async code. The code retains a lot of the imperative qualities you might be using. You don't have to completely change things to take advantage of this; the compiler via handles it all.

Answer (score 0):

[Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) (long PDF), by Chris Okasaki.

Answer (score 0):

A teacher of mine used to joke that the greatest example of functional code is the code that is not written.